# Q.js - how to access a cached element

Tags: javascript, q

Ok, so I'm using Q.js to help with keeping users notified of a potentially long calculation going on asynchronously (using setTimeout with zero delay to repeatedly call a function a set number of times).

However, this does not work:

```
var status = d3.select('#status');

var t = transfer({
    N: 100
});

t.then(function (values) {

    status.text('');
    column_chart(values);

}, function (error) {

    status.text('There was an error calculating the transfer probabilities')

}, function (progress) {

    status.text('Calculating ' + Math.round(progress) + '%');

});
```

For some reason the status element is undefined inside the resolve, reject and progress functions. However if I replace each `status.text` with `d3.select('#status').text` then it all works fine. I'm a bit confused as to why I can't used a cached element?

Answer (score 1):

OK, there was a problem with the name of my cached element!

```
var status = d3.select('#status');
```

Changing its name fixed the problem

```
var statusEl = d3.select('#status');
```

It turns out inside my promise functions status was the raw HTML element which of course had no text method. This is that weird thing where all DOM elements with ID's are added to the global window object...